# Google Calendar meeting to alternate on specific days

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to make a meeting on (Windows Web Platform) Google Calendar be on Mondays, Wednesdays, and Fridays one week, then Tuesdays and Thursdays next week, then the following week back to MWF, then TT the next week, rinse, repeat? I know I can schedule two separate recurring meetings - one for MWF and the other for TT, but is there a way to do this within a single meeting? Without involving 3rd-party apps.

I googled this online but it seems there is no quick and simple way to do such a thing.